# Initializing Jetty+Jersey

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to initialize Jetty with the following code:

```
URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(config.getPort()).build();
ResourceConfig resConfig = new ResourceConfig(GetFutureTimetableCommand.class);
Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, resConfig);

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setDescriptor("WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");
context.setResourceBase("WebContent");
context.setContextPath("rest/*");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
```

My Resource looks like this:

```
@Path("/timetable")
public class GetFutureTimetableCommand extends CMSCommand {

@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public CMSBean execute(@PathParam("param") String params) {
    System.out.println("GOOD");
    return new FutureTimetable(8202L, DateTime.now().plusDays(2));
}
}
```

And from the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/timetable
```

But nothing really happens, what am I doing wrong??

Comment: When you say "nothing really happens", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I put a break point inside 'execute' method of the resource and it never stops there.

Comment: Debuggers can have bugs, unfortunately. What about in the browser, what happens there?

Comment: blank page.

At the beginning I worked with Tomcat and Jersey 1.18 and it worked fine. but I've decided to embed Jetty in my server and upgrade to Jersey 2.5 ...

Answer (score 2):

I have found that enabling [MBeans with monitoring statistics](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.5.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MONITORING_STATISTICS_MBEANS_ENABLED) invaluable when trying to determine why a resource isn't executing.

Add the below to your Jersey Servlet definition in your `web.xml` and connect `JVisualVM` or `JConsole` to see lots of data on deployed resources.

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>jersey.config.server.monitoring.statistics.mbeans.enabled</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I appreciate this isn't an answer to your problem, but hopefully should help you find it.

Will

Answer (score 0):

It seems only the root context path is taken into account when jersey is used together with jetty as per Jersey documentation (others are just ignored):
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html

You probably need to change the context path with:

```
context.setContextPath("/");
```